# How to use RobustScaler on all columns?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

Right now I have a a 2 by 2 numpy array. By using RobustScaler, it normalizes each column one at a time, whereas I wish to normalize everything all at once. Is there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation the [RobustScaler](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.RobustScaler.html):

> removes the median and scales the data according to the quantile range

So you need to compute the median and the quantile range for the whole array, for this you can use the [np.median](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.median.html) and [np.percentile](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html) functions, this is what sklearn does under the hood. The code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import robust_scale

data = np.array([[3, 6],
                 [9, 12]], dtype=np.float64)
result = robust_scale(data, axis=0)
print(result)

reshape = data.reshape((1, 4))
result = robust_scale(reshape, axis=1)

me = np.median(data.flat) # 7.5
percentiles = np.percentile(data, (25.0, 75.0)) # 5.25 9.75

data -= me
data /= (percentiles[1] - percentiles[0])

print(data)
```

**Output**

```
[[-1. -1.]
 [ 1.  1.]]
[[-1.         -0.33333333]
 [ 0.33333333  1.        ]]
```

In the example I used `(25.0, 75.0)` because this are the default values for the quantile range, also the function [robust_scale](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.robust_scale.html#sklearn.preprocessing.robust_scale) is equivalent to the functionality of RobustScaler (section See Also on the documentation).

Comment: This works! However, why did you use data.flat instead of just data?

Comment: @ChrisWang you are right! You can drop the axis parameter and just use data directly.